# Magento 2.4 MSI : How to programmatically set Notify Stock Level on Source and SKU

Tags: magento2, msi

I would like to set Notify Qty from a script that reads a CSV file with Source, SKU and NotifyQty. It would probably need to enable notify qty for the products as well.

I can do it with SQL query to inventory_low_stock_notification_configuration.notify_stock_qty, but that's probably not the right way.

Comment: Hi!
You have sku and qty inside some csv file and you want to import it from PHP script, is that right?

Comment: Hi! Yes, that's right. I have the rest of the script ready, so it's reading the csv, but I don't know how to access the notify qty correctly

Comment: Ok, let me prepare answer for you :)

Comment: Could you change your answer so it contains information about import from CSV file?

Comment: Are you ok with cli run script?

Comment: Change the question, you mean? Just did. Yes, I can run cli script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is example CSV file (`sku_qty.csv`):

```
source_code,sku,qty
default,SOME_SKU1,2
default,SOME_SKU2,3
default,SOME_SKU3,4
```

This is the code to run:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . './../app/bootstrap.php';

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

// Init Magento
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

// Get Object Manager instance
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

// Construct Factory object
/* @var $sourceItemConfigurationFactory \Magento\InventoryLowQuantityNotification\Model\SourceItemConfigurationFactory */
$sourceItemConfigurationFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\InventoryLowQuantityNotification\Model\SourceItemConfigurationFactory');

// Construct Multiple Save object
/* @var $saveMultiple \Magento\InventoryLowQuantityNotification\Model\ResourceModel\SourceItemConfiguration\SaveMultiple */
$saveMultiple = $objectManager->get('Magento\InventoryLowQuantityNotification\Model\ResourceModel\SourceItemConfiguration\SaveMultiple');


// Create CSV file handle
$inputFile = fopen(__DIR__ . "/sku_qty.csv", "r");

// Get CSV headers
$headers = fgetcsv($inputFile);

// Init array of config objects
$sourceItemsConfiguration = [];

// Iterate CSV file
$n = 0;
while (($row = fgetcsv($inputFile)) !== false) {
    $n++;
    // Init source item config instance and set data
    $sourceItemConfiguration = $sourceItemConfigurationFactory->create();
    $sourceItemConfiguration->setSourceCode($row[0]);
    $sourceItemConfiguration->setSku($row[1]);
    $sourceItemConfiguration->setNotifyStockQty($row[2]);

    $sourceItemsConfiguration[] = $sourceItemConfiguration;
}

try {
    // Save data
    $saveMultiple->execute($sourceItemsConfiguration);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I like to put my file inside `script` directory, so I run them like that `php script/test.php` from Magento root directory.

Comment: Thank you so much @dudzio, it worked like a charm! I've upvoted, but I have not reached 15 reps yet.

Comment: Happy to hear! :) Thanks! 
I tried to run `save()` method on `$sourceItemConfiguration` inside while loop, but unfortunately there is a bug that results in `The resource isn't set.` error :(

Comment: That's what I was trying too, but I thought it was my lack of knowledge, not a bug! Happy that you found a different solution!